# Moving from nginx to Netlify or Github pages

Tags: nginx, github-pages, netlify

We plan to move our static websites from dedicated servers running nginx to Netlify / Github Pages.

Currently we run nginx as our web server. Nginx allows our content to be organised in flat hierarchy as shown below and let us map each URL to the file system path like. For example,

- /web/main -> for https://example.com/
- /web/docs -> for https://example.com/docs/
- /web/jsapp -> for https://example.com/app/

As I understand from the Netlify / Github Pages documentation, we may need to reorganize our content in deep hierarchy like following (please correct me here):

- /web/main
- /web/main/docs
- /web/main/jsapps

Is this a correct understanding? if yes, we would like to avoid that. I hope that Netlify / Github Pages will have something to organize the url and content path individually like nginx does but I couldn't find anything other than redirect (which is not what I am looking for).

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Correct. Most of it will come down to reorganizing your static website in a specific structure. You will have to make sure you have an `index.html` at the root. If you plan on using something like Jekyll or Hugo or even Gatsby, that could help with pipelining assets, building URLS, etc. but moving a compiled static site will need to follow a specific structure. In the end, github pages hosts that and not the engine.

If you leave anything on the nginx too, say css, then you will need server side push too. A lot of variables there. Small ones however. Restructuring is anyway the better way to do it, if it is all static content.